# How do i link libstdc++, libwinpthread, and libgcc to my visual studio project?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++14

i want my .exe can be opened in the client computer. But when the client computer opened the .exe. It says that it dont have a libgcc,libwinpthread, and libstdc++ DLL files. How do i link the DLL files when i build the solution/project? (I tried to search google but there's no luck that i found.) (Note : My Visual Studio Version is 2019 and i use MinGW64)

Comment: Either link your dependencies statically, or ship them with the executable.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili how do i link it statically in Visual Studio 2019?

Comment: You should Google it.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili i already... but i still cant fix it